# Error with group(...) from SQlite to PostgreSQL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to upload my app to heroku but it gives me an error in this statement:

```
@exhibition.enrolments.select(:id).group('payment_id')
```

***ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "enrolments.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function***

In SQlite I didn't have any errors, but in Production I have it.

The question is: I have this:

```
enrolment_id | payment_id | ....
1            | 1          | ....
2            | 1          | ....
3            | 2          | ....
4            | 3          | ....
5            | 3          | ....
```

And I want to get the enrolments' ids 2,3 and 4.

I tried this too:

```
@exhibition.enrolments.select(:id).group('enrolment.id, payment_id')
```

It works but it just gives me all entries, obviously...

I read to many posts about this but I didn't get the solucion...

Any help? Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I mean:

> And I want to get the enrolments' ids **2**,**3** and **5**.

The greatest enrolment_id in each block of payments with the same id.

Thx Frank Heikens

Comment: Have you tried searching for "must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function" and using any of the approaches you find? PS: Stop developing on top of one database and deploying on another, Rails/ActiveRecord gives you essentially no useful portability.

Comment: Yes, I tried and still reading, but I don't get any solution that may work for me. And you are right, but it's just my first app in rails :/ Ty

Comment: "And I want to get the enrolments' ids 2,3 and 4." Could you explain why these id's should popup? What kind of logic should there be in your query to select just these values. I don't see how GROUP BY should work, I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So give it the aggregate function it wants?

```
@exhibition.enrolments.select(:id).group('payment_id').max(:id)
```

Alternatively, you could order the records and use distinct

```
@exhibition.enrolments.order('payment_id DESC').select(:payment_id).distinct
```

Comment: I can't vote your answer, but it work... Thank very much! It's just what I needed.